# Google Javascript map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dictionary, javascript

I want to display map with just map border and country name in that country without any extra information like sub-areas of that country.I just want to display country name and want assign one click handler to country name using Javascript.

Is this possible using google map?

Please suggest me some javascript api or any library or Google Map API that will help me ..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also a Map Chart type in the Google Chart API.  This lets you customize fill colors, assign data to countries, enable only certain countries, etc.

The Map Chart documentation is here: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/new_map_charts.html

and the page to create an image map for the chart is here http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/json_format.html (but I have not used it with the map chart)

Answer (score 1):

This will literally walk you through everything you need for the google maps API, its super useful trust me.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Others have already suggested the Google Maps API (and provided links for you), which is indeed very good. Feel free to use it and accept one of those answers if you do.

But I thought it would be helpful to point out that there are several other options as well.

Microsoft has a mapping system which is in direct competition to Google's, as does Yahoo. Both of these maps have APIs which allow you to use them directly in your own site in a similar way to Google's.

Yahoo's developer site provides details of how to use their maps here: http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/ and the developer instructions for Microsoft Maps are here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx

Finally, there is an Open Source map, called [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org), which again provides an API for you to use on your site. The quality of the maps in OpenStreetMap is generally pretty good, but the real killer feature is that if there are errors (or new streets are built, etc), they encourage you to log in an submit changes which can then be incorporated into the maps. They also have the advantage of not being tied to any large corporation as the others all all.

You can find out more about the OpenStreetMap API from their wiki page, here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Api

Hope that helps.

Comment: But is it possible to display only country names in map and assign handler to them...

Answer (score 0):

Ill suggest an API: The Google Maps API